# Configure Request Time Out in Kestral Web Server

Tags: asp.net-core, sqlconnection, connection-timeout

I have a project in asp.net core 2.2 and hosted many applications under the same project. It is hosted on Kestral server only and not IIS

I have configured the default request time out in **application.json** file under the project and it is passed in the connectionstring.

I want to configure the timeout on the API level such that one API can be with 1 minute request time out and other can be something else.

I If someone has any answer please let here know.

My **appsettings.json** is something like below -

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "UserConncetionString": "Server=*******;Database=********;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;Integrated Security=false;User Id=developer;Password=********",
    "SecureKey": "********"
  },
  "ConnectionTimeOut": {
    "TimeOut": 60
  },
```

Not able to configure the timeouts on individual API levels.